When I install an .exe application in WineBottler, it shows an error reading "Prefix creation exited with error"
It says the following in Console:
  Model Name: Mac
  Model Identifier: Mac15,12
  Model Number: MXCV3LL/A
  Chip: Unknown
  Total Number of Cores: 8 (4 performance and 4 efficiency)
  Memory: 16 GB
  System Firmware Version: 10151.121.1
  OS Loader Version: 10151.121.1
  Serial Number (system): CP6Q0TC34J
  Hardware UUID: BF100DE2-F44C-5831-BEC6-D8BA7EB1074C
  Provisioning UDID: BF100DE2-F44C-5831-BEC6-D8BA7EB1074C
  Activation Lock Status: Disabled

....
###BOTTLING### Enabling CoreAudio, Colors, Antialiasing  and flat menus...
/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources/bottler.sh: line 134: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine: Bad CPU type in executable
### LOG ### Command '/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine regedit /tmp/reg.reg' returned status 126.

....
###ERROR### Command '/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine regedit /tmp/reg.reg' returned status 126.
Task returned with status 1.\

